# Shouldn't System-Settings-->Display "see" the monitor correctly?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, shutdown, monitor

This is a 12.04 Intel 32-bit system with 8GB Ram and a Gigabyte GT220 NVidia graphics card.

The resolution displayed by System-Settings-->Display is correct, but the monitor is detected as "Laptop", instead of "Samsung SyncMaster", which is what NVIDIA X Server Settings find.

I do not need 3D acceleration, since i do not play any games.

Should i get rid of the NVIDIA additional drivers? 
Could it solve the Shutdown incapability problem that has been plaguing my system since the 11.10 update?

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem that the monitor is detected as "Laptop". I have this too on a system that runs perfectly.

I wouldn't recommend to remove the proprietary driver, because that could mean that you couldn't use Gnome 3 / Unity anymore. I don't think that the driver has something to do with Shutdown problems.